# Wake-on-LAN stops working after a few hours

Tags: power-management, switch, wake-on-lan, arp, magic-packet

I have a Linux server (Ubuntu 12.04.03) which serves as the internet gateway for our LAN of about 15 PCs.  That is, **eth0** on the Linux server is the Internet, and **eth1** plugs into an unmanaged switch (a simple Linksys 16-port switch (EZXS16W)).  All the LAN PCs connect to that switch.  The Linux server manages the DHCP details and the Internet gateway/NAT-routing stuff.

I'm trying to get Wake-On-LAN (WOL) working for one of the LAN PCs (running Windows 7) so that the Linux server can start it up.  I have successfully configured the BIOS and Windows network drivers so that WOL will work for a while.  That is, I shut the PC down, walk over to the Linux server, and send the magic packet.

```
> wakeonlan -i 10.8.8.11 '6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E'
```

**This works**.  The PC immediately starts up, and all is well.

However if I shut down the PC, leave, and come several hours later and try the "wakeonlan" command again, nothing happens.  The PC doesn't not power on.

So, I figured the problem must be the ARP tables.  This seemed promising, because the Linux server had indeed "forgotten" about the Windows PC.

```
> arp -a -n
? (10.8.8.3) at 00:21:9b:01:ab:0c [ether] on eth1
? (10.8.8.247) at 00:80:77:d9:70:1e [ether] on eth1
? (70.60.233.185) at 90:6e:bb:f0:c4:82 [ether] on eth0
```

So I figured I would add a permanent ARP record:

```
> arp -i eth1 -s 10.8.8.11 '6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E'
> arp -a -n
? (10.8.8.3) at 00:21:9b:01:ab:0c [ether] on eth1
? (10.8.8.11) at 6c:62:6d:ef:86:2e [ether] PERM on eth1
? (10.8.8.247) at 00:80:77:d9:70:1e [ether] on eth1
? (70.60.233.185) at 90:6e:bb:f0:c4:82 [ether] on eth0
```

However, this did not help.  Running the "wakeonlan" command did not start up the PC.  Neither did my attempts to use the broadcast address or a different program:

```
> wakeonlan 6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E
> etherwake -i eth1 6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E
> etherwake -b -i eth1 6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E
```

So, I have a couple of questions.

1) What am I doing wrong? :-)

2) Is there such a thing as an ARP table/cache on an unmanaged switch?  That is, even though I've added the permanent ARP entry on the Linux server, is it possible that the Linksys EZXS16W has lost the knowledge of which port it should use for contacting 6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E ?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Shouldn't this also work without `-i 10.8.8.11`? I thought `-i` would be used with a broadcast address. Either way... after some time the `10.8.8.11` isn't valid anymore so leave it out (remove the `-i 10.8.8.11` part) and see if it works then.

Comment: Rik, thanks but as I mentioned, using the broadcast address (`wakeonlan 6C:62:6D:EF:86:2E1`) also doesn't work.  The "wakeonlan" program doesn't allow me to specify an interface (eth0, eth1), so I tried etherwake (with and without the broadcast address) on eth1 specifically, but still no luck.

Comment: Did you set your NIC to not go into power saving mode when not in use. In Device Manager within Windows you'll have to look at your Network Card and uncheck the box to allow it to be turned off to save energy. There could still be other settings pushing you NIC to go into deep sleep-mode but check that one first.

Comment: Assuming you have other Windows PCs on the network, you could try using a Windows utility such as:http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html from one of those. If it always works from there, then the problem likely sits with the Linux server or the commands you are running. If not, it may be a switch problem. I've used wol extensively in the past on hundreds of machines and have only ever used a "wol macaddress" format... Never needed to refer to the ip address.